# How to remove highlight from textured NSWindow?

Tags: swift, macos

There's my problem:

I have a textured NSWindow in storyboard:

[image: IB]

but it has highlight on the window's top edge:

[image: Highlight]

I don't like that highlight on the window's top edge. How to remove this highlight or at least replace it with the same background color?

Note: Calculator's app window doesn't have that highlight (or it's very very subtle), while other apps have it. Look:

[image: Calculator.app]

I prefere to get the same result as Calculator app.

P.S.: I set window's background color in my ViewController like that:

```
// BlueColor: NSColor
view.window?.backgroundColor = BlueColor
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's not about drawing on full pixels rather than drawing into middle (draw at 0.5,1.5,2.5 instead of 0,1,2,3). Look here at 1 pixel line https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html

Comment: I don't really understand what are you talking about. I'm not drawing at all, that's a default NSWindow thing.

Comment: Sry I thought you use custom drawing. Remove shadow "setHasShadow:NO" + setOpaque:NO + setAlphaValue:1.0f + setTitlebarAppearsTransparent:YES => this is what calc app does

Comment: Your solution didn't worked :(
https://i.gyazo.com/50995aac423193ea0c2cded9d292b248.png

Comment: It's a comment, not solution. You can use hopper and look into internals of calc by yourself

Comment: "You can use hopper and look into internals of calc by yourself" Really? Where can I find its source?

Comment: Compiled source you have inside Calc app package http://www.hopperapp.com/tutorial.html If you really want what you want you should have better attitude if you want help from others

Comment: I'm sorry, if I'm being rude, but I'm trying to solve this problem for 3-4 days, that's so frustrating. I would like to get rid of this highlight, make the window flat colored, but remain close and minimized buttons. I can achieve flat colored window with styleMask: NSBorderlessWindowMask, but it removes buttons. Anyway, thank you for your efforts trying to help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highlight is drawn by the the window's theme frame when you set the textured background mask. (You can investigate this via Visual View Debugging in Xcode).

To achieve a flat window frame (without that highlight), you have to:

- Turn off the "Textured" flag
- Set the `NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask` style mask (necessary for the next step)
- Set `NSWindow's titlebarAppearsTransparent` to true

You could add the following to the part where you set the window's background color:

```
self.view.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blueColor()
self.view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
let existingStyleMask = self.view.window!.styleMask
self.view.window?.styleMask = existingStyleMask|NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask
```

This will give you a window with a flat top border:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, you're my hero! :)

Comment: I cannot award you with bounty right now, but I'll do it as soon it'll be available (in 6 hours).